# On the Epson RX8900 RTC, why when I start a fixed cycle timer the first cycle is too short by up to 1 second?

Tags: rtc

[image]
This is the signal diagram from the datasheet. The time period pointed to be the red arrow here is wrong.

In fact, the fixed cycle timer uses the internal second (minute) register respectively to update the fixed cycle timer when using the second (minute) cycle clock. So if you use the 1 second timer clock, all interrupts will only happen the internal seconds register updates, and if you use the minute clock, then the timer interrupt can only occur when the clock minutes register updates. This means the first period can be randomly short by up to 1 second (minute).

The only way to have a fixed cycle timer with a 1 second clock start at an exact time is to use the RESET bit in the control register to clear the prescaler at the moment you want to start the timer. Note that this will also align the RTC's seconds counter to this same moment.

Additionally if you want the first period of a fixed timer using the minute cycle clock to be correct, you must set the seconds time to 0 when starting the cycle timer. Note that this means that you are changing the actual RTC time also.

If your period is less than 64 seconds, then you could also use the 1/64th second cycle clock and set your counter to 64 times the number of seconds you want in your cycle. There will still be jitter in the first period of the timer, but it will be less than 1/64th of a second rather than up to a full second.